# System.OutOfMemoryException while after execution for an hour

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

why I got this "**System.OutOfMemoryException**"

this code is provide service to read smart card from smart card reader and put result in textbox that was focus in any application. while it running (more than 60 minutes) I got error throw out. what happen in my case?

please advice

```
class Program
    {
        static bool infinity = true;
        static WinSCard sCard;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                sCard = new WinSCard();

                while (infinity) {

                    sCard.EstablishContext();                   //establis smart card reader resourete manager
                    sCard.ListReaders();                        //get list of smart card reader

                    string readerName = sCard.ReaderNames[0];   //the first smart card reader in the list

                    sCard.WaitForCardPresent(readerName);       //block execution until smart card was attached to the reader
                    sCard.Connect(readerName);                  //connect to a smart card

//                  Console.WriteLine( "ATR: 0x" + sCard.AtrString );


                    byte[] cmdApdu = { 0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 00 };    // get card UID ...
                    byte[] respApdu = new byte[6];
                    int respLength = respApdu.Length;

                    //submit command to smart card and get a return result
                    sCard.Transmit(cmdApdu, cmdApdu.Length, respApdu, ref respLength);

                    //Convert Bute[] to HexString and finally Integer
                    int num = Int32.Parse(ByteArrayToString(respApdu, respLength), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                    Console.WriteLine("GET CARD UID ==> " + num);

                    //Send Result to any input that currently got focus
                    SendKeys.SendWait(num.ToString());

                    sCard.WaitForCardRemoval(readerName);   //block execution until smart card was removed to the reader
                    sCard.Disconnect();                     //terminated connection to a smart card
                    sCard.ReleaseContext();                 //freely any resource allocated under the context
                }
            }
            catch (WinSCardException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( ex.WinSCardFunctionName + " 0x" + ex.Status.ToString( "X08" ) + " " + ex.Message );
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please press any key...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba, int length)
        {
            StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(length * 2);
            foreach (byte b in ba)
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
            return hex.ToString().Replace("9000","");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It could be really helpful if you could provide exactly WHICH line throws the exception, and the full stacktrace and stuff like this !

Comment: I want to know it too but sharpdevelop doesn't show which cause this error (For this error)

Comment: as you can see from the "comments" posted as an answer - this question is really hard to answer as it's right now  - without knowing what happens behind all your `scard.[Method]` stuff it's indeed impossible to answer - just try some random memory profiler and have a look at the stuff that stick in memory - most likely some event-handler that keeps stuff from getting GCed

Comment: I don't understand what SharpDevelop has to do in this, even if the program was compiled and executed out of the IDE, you just have to properly catch the exception, call ToString() and write its content in a textbox. If the EXE is built with pdb you will also have line numbers.

Comment: @CarstenKönig  sCard.WaitForCardPresent(readerName); seem to be the cause and I have no idea how to solve this. as you mention it was behind the scene. so poor

Comment: @Richard I don't understand too.

Comment: I have found one confusing result. after I use dotMemory(tool like ANTS Memory Profiler)  there is nothing wrong with memory. and I found out that if I start application by open .exe not run from sharpdevelop there is no memory leak problem. on the other hand, if I start run via sharpdevelop memory is continue increasing so, the problem is come from shapedevelop 5.0 RC ??

Comment: @Richard maybe this is the reason why sharpdevelop not provide the error line because of bug in itself??

Answer (score 1):

Are there any classes in your code which implement `IDisposable` and you are not disposing them, or are their any PInvoke calls, which need additional calls to cleanup any memory allocated by them.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that sCard.ListReaders() causes your issue, so that I would analyze the code there in more details. I assume there is some internal collection which is never cleaned up and your sCard is static variable. You can either debug/write unit test or use memory profiling tool such as ANTS Memory Profiler (create initial snapshot and then after 10 mins and compare which instance consumes your memory)

Answer (score 0):

It could help not to reuse your `WinSCard` object in your loop. Just create a new instance at the every beginning.
And you don't need to put this object to a static member, use it as local variable.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            while (infinity) {

                var sCard = new WinSCard();

                sCard.EstablishContext();                   //establis smart card reader resourete manager
                sCard.ListReaders();                        //get list of smart card reader
```

And if `WinSCard` implements `IDisposable` wrap it in an using statement to make sure to free potentially no more used resources:

```
                using(var sCard = new WinSCard())
                {
                    sCard.EstablishContext();                   //establis smart card reader resourete manager
                    sCard.ListReaders();                        //get list of smart card reader
```

Comment: After I use dotMemory(tool like ANTS Memory Profiler) there is nothing wrong with memory. and I found out that if I start application by open .exe not run from sharpdevelop there is no memory leak problem. on the other hand, if I start run via sharpdevelop memory is continue increasing so, the problem is come from shapedevelop 5.0 RC ??

Comment: I don't know wheter this is an issue of any development system or not. Even I do not care. My suggestion is a basic programming principle wich I suppose to follow regardless of development system or programming language. It's better to avoid mistakes in principle than to look after reasons for failures under special circumstances